# RoR: form_tag, redirect after submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, redirect

I guess, I'm missing something...

We've got a form, made like this:

```
    <%= form_tag(controller: "contact",action: "send_us") %>
```

We've got this controller method:

```
      def send_us
        @name = params[:name]
        @email = params[:email]
        @question = params[:question]
        Notifier.welcome(@name,@email,@question).deliver
        redirect_to 'http://mysitepath.com.ua/ua/contact/contact_us'
      end
```

Assume that app is living on http://myserver.com.ua/ and user will rich it through http://mysitepath.com.ua/ua/. So when user comes to http://mysitepath.com.ua/ua/ he'll see app, from http://myserver.com.ua/ (nothing complicated)

So, when I go to http://myserver.com.ua/contact/contact_us (the page with my form) the form behaves correctly and submission redirects right to http://mysitepath.com.ua/ua/contact/contact_us .

But, when I go to http://mysitepath.com.ua/ua/contact/contact_us and submit a form, it redirects me to http://mysitepath.com.ua/contact/contact_us , without "/ua/".

Can u help me to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem: 
The post request on  `http://myserver.com.ua/` goes to `/` and that is good 
The same post request on  `http://mysitepath.com.ua/ua/` goes to `/` but I expected it to go to /ua/.